# Let $T \in T_{2}^{1}$ be associated with the map given as $Z(A,B) = AB - BA$, where $A,B \in V$, find $[T]_B$.

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, tensors

Let $V$ be the space of all $3 \times 3$ antisymmetric matrices. And let $T \in T_{2}^{1}$ (tensors) be associated with the map given as $Z(A,B) = AB - BA$, where $A,B \in V$.

The basis of $V$ is given as a classic basis of antisymmetric matrices: 
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\!, \\[2pt]$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\!, \\[2pt]$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &  0& 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\!, \\[2pt]$

Find $[T]_B$.

I just have no idea how to work with tensors given like that. Should I write matrix $A$ as an arbitrary antisymmetric matrix and then apply the $Z$ map? But how is this a tensor problem?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You have written the same matrix thrice for your basis.

Comment: Yeah thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your basis of antisymmetric matrices is given by $A_1, A_2, A_3$ and its dual basis on $V^*$ is denoted by $A_1^*, A_2^*, A_3^*$, then a basis of $T_2^1(V)$ is given by
$$(A_k \otimes A_i^* \otimes A_j^*)_{k,i,j}.$$
I think that you are asked here to express $T$ in this basis.

Do you know how to do it from here?

---

The identification $T_2^1 (V) \cong \text{Bilinear maps}~\colon V × V  → V$ is actually an isomorphism of linear spaces given by
\begin{align*}
T_2^1(V) &→ (\text{Bilinear maps}\colon V × V → V),\\
w \otimes φ \otimes ψ &↦ [(v,v') ↦ φ(v)·ψ(v')·w]
\end{align*}
Hence, if you want to express $T ∈ T_2^1(V)$ in terms of the basis above, you can instead express its corresponding bilinear map $Z$ in terms of the images of this bases, namely the bilinear maps
$$α_{k,i,j} \colon V × V → V,~(v,v') ↦ A_i^*(v)·A_j^*(v')·A_k.$$
So now, there is some linear combination
$$Z = \sum_{κ,ρ,σ} λ_{κ,ρ,σ}α_{κ,ρ,σ}$$
and you are interested in those $λ_{κ,ρ,σ}$. To get them, just plug in $A_i$ and $A_j$ – all summands except for $λ_{k,i,j}α_{k,i,j}$ for $k=1,2,3$ will vanish. So just express the result of $Z(A_i,A_j)$ in terms of $A_k$.

Summary: This all amounts to calculating $Z(A_i,A_j)$.

Comment: I think I dont know what to do next

Comment: @Leif I have expanded my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the wonderful explanation.